# Deserialize using BinaryReader fails

Tags: c#

I have a `byte[]` and I need to deserialize it.

I wrote this code

```
  using(MemodyStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)
  {
       using(BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
       {
             Person p = new Person();
             p.id = reader.ReadString();
             p.age = reader.ReadInt32();
       }
  }
```

But I don't understand why I see that the `BinaryReader` return 0 each time => and the `byteArray` does not contain 0.

Where is my mistake ?

How to do it in another way?

Adding ..

the i write this data in the same order

```
   using(BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(stream))
   {
         w.Write(person.id);
         w.Write(person.age);
   }
```

Comment: How did you write your `byteArray`? The `ReadString` and the `ReadInt32` require the data to be formatted in a certain way... Especially the `ReadString` is quite particular on how it is formatted, and it is improbable that something other than a `BinaryWriter` could format the data in that way.

Comment: the writer is done from other application ( wrote in C++ )

Comment: yes, id is string @ age is int32

Comment: you have to decide: the writer is done in C++ or the writer is the second block of code.

Comment: did the c++ program write c-style strings?

Comment: i wrote two writers . .. first in C# to see if its working ( tester ) but in the integration i need to get the byte[] from other application that is C++ application

Comment: Does it work when using the C# writer?

Comment: :) yes, with C# tester its work totally

Comment: Then add `c++` as tag??

Comment: I recommend taking a look at the binary details of en/decoding strings in c# as well as c++. .NET uses little-endian, btw.

Comment: try already .... used encoding ... i also remove all the strings and put struct using only int and bytes .. also get 0 on the binaryStream Reader

Comment: how do you serialize byteArray?

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman And the `ReadString`/`WriteString` prepend the length of the number is a strange 7 bits extendible format. (if the number is up to 127 then 1 byte, from 127 to ??? then 2 bytes and so on, explained here http://dpatrickcaldwell.blogspot.it/2011/09/7-bit-encoding-with-binarywriter-in-net.html)

Comment: Add the writing details to the question itself. Readers shouldn't have to dig through comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think every things is ok, problem it must be in serilize :

i use this code and ok :

```
        int myInt = 100;
        byte[] byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(myInt);

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray)) {
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream)) {
                var i = reader.ReadInt32();
            }
        }
```

Comment: ok, i also tested with some serilize that i wrote - and i also get good result.

Comment: @Yanshof can you explain how do you serialize?

Comment: Yes, by using the BinaryWriter.Write

Comment: @Yanshof i mean write full code that you write to serialize byteArray